# Dynamic location for PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer

Tags: java, spring, properties

i have annotation-based bean configuration for placeholder.
With the help of this placeholder, i can use properties values i want very easily.

```
@Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer initPlaceholder() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeholder = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        placeholder.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("some.properties"));
        placeholder.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);

        return placeholder;
    }
```

How i can set up this placeholder with ${some.properties} dynamic values?

```
placeholder.setLocation(new ClassPathResource(ANY_PROPERTIES));
```

I can not use initPlaceholder(String property)...

Comment: So, you want to get property without usage of placeholder? In such case spring profiles will be better I think... (select properties file according to some profile).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have done about this was create my own PropertyPlaceHolder (to get an external property file)

```
public class MyPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer {

public static final String ANY_PROPERTY = "ANY_PROPERTY";

private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(MyPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.class);

@Override
protected void loadProperties(Properties props) throws IOException {

    String anyProperty = System.getProperty(ANY_PROPERTY);

    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(anyProperty)) {
        LOG.info("Using default configuration");
        super.loadProperties(props);

    } else {
        LOG.info("Setting HDFS LOCATION PATH TO : " + anyProperty);

        try {
            Path pt = new Path(anyProperty);
            Configuration conf = new Configuration();
            conf.set(FileSystem.FS_DEFAULT_NAME_KEY, anyProperty);
            FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
            FSDataInputStream fileOpen = fs.open(pt);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileOpen));
            props.load(br);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error(e);
        }
    }

}
```